# Number of coin tosses needed to establish bias

Tags: probability, combinations, binomial-distribution

How many consecutive tails would you need to establish that a coin is biased ($P_{heads} < 0.5$)

Null: $P_{heads} = p = 0.5$

So need $(1-p)^n < 0.05$ to establish bias at 95% confidence one sided

$\implies 0.5^n < 0.05$

$\implies n > \frac{\log(0.05)} {\log(0.5)}$

$\implies n \ge 5$

So it seems like we only need 5 tails to conclude that coin is biased?? That seems very low. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: $n > 4$ or more precisely $n > 4.32$ would suggest at least five tails not four.  This becomes $n>5.32$ or at least six the same if you did a two sided test (how do you know heads might be unlikely while tails cannot be unlikely?)

Comment: sure, changed to 5.  But I dont understand how it changes to 6 for 2 sided

Comment: You want $p^n + (1-p)^n < 0.05$ when $p=0.5$ and this leads to $n > \frac{\log(0.025)}{\log(0.5)} \approx 5.32$

Comment: got it, thanks.